# How can I load the selected items in listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I'm working on a class project and I'm having difficulty in setting the selected items in a listbox.  I've created a dog class with contains an observable collection of breeds.  On my main screen I have a list box from where you can choose a dog.  The update dog screen is opened when a dog is chosen and the update dog button event is triggered.  In the update dog screen there is a list box with all of the dog breeds.  My question is, how do I set the selected items of the list box to link up to the dog's breeds?

Here is the code for the btnUpdateDog_Click event:

```
    private void btnUpdateDog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.lstDogListBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Dog selectedDog = (Dog)this.lstDogListBox.SelectedItem;
            var dogId = selectedDog.DogId;
            var _selectedDog = _dogRepository.Fetch(dogId).SingleOrDefault();

            UpdateDogWindow updateDogWindow = new UpdateDogWindow(dogId);

            updateDogWindow.Owner = windowClientApplication;

            updateDogWindow.DataContext = _selectedDog;

            updateDogWindow.ShowDialog();

            if (updateDogWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                LoadSearchResults();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the constructor for the UpdateDogWindow

```
    public UpdateDogWindow(int criteria)
    {
        _dogRepository = new DogRespository();

        var _dogQuery = _dogRepository.Fetch(criteria);

        this.DataContext = _dogQuery;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Here is the XAML code for the UpdateDogWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="ClientApplication.UpdateDogWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Objects="clr-namespace:SGVHS_VCDB.Database.Objects;assembly=SGVHS_VCDB.Database.Objects"
        Title="Update Dog"
        Height="300" 
        Width="800" 
        Background="#FFD6DBDD" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow" 
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Objects:Dog />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Canvas>
        <Label 
            Canvas.Left="20" 
            Canvas.Top="20" 
            Content="_Dog Name:" 
            Height="36" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Name="lblDogName" />
        <TextBox 
            Canvas.Left="130" 
            Canvas.Top="20" 
            Height="38" 
            Width="250" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Text="{Binding Path=DogName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Name="txtUpdateDogName" />
        <Label 
            Canvas.Left="20" 
            Canvas.Top="80" 
            Content="_Intake Date:" 
            Height="36" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Name="lblIntakeDate" />
        <DatePicker 
            Canvas.Left="170" 
            Canvas.Top="81" 
            Height="38" 
            Width="175" 
            FontSize="18" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding IntakeDate}"
            Name="dtoUpdateIntakeDate"/>
        <Label
            Canvas.Left="20" 
            Canvas.Top="140"
            Height="36"
            Content="_Unavailable Date:"
            FontSize="18"
            Name="lblUnavailableDate"/>
        <DatePicker 
            Canvas.Left="170" 
            Canvas.Top="141" 
            Height="38" 
            Width="175" 
            FontSize="18" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding UnavailableDate}" 
            Name="dtoUnavailableDate"/>
        <GroupBox 
            Canvas.Left="400" 
            Canvas.Top="22" 
            Header="Breeds" 
            Height="169" 
            Width="363" 
            FontSize="18" 
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Name="grpBreeds">
            <ListBox 
                DisplayMemberPath="BreedName"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectedValuePath="BreedName"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Breed, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Name="lstUpdateDogBreedList" />
        </GroupBox>
        <CheckBox 
            Canvas.Left="20" 
            Canvas.Top="200" 
            Content="Adopted" 
            Height="32" 
            FontSize="18"
            IsChecked="{Binding Adopted}"
            Name="chkAdopted"/>
        <Button 
            Canvas.Left="637" 
            Canvas.Top="205" 
            Content="Done" 
            Height="30" 
            Width="120" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Name="btnUpdateDogDone" />        
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I tried to set the binding for the breed list to twoway, why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a homework. The answer is use CollectionViewSource for filtering.
You may use CollectionViewSource's for filtering,sorting etc.

http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/08/03/filtering-collectionview-data-in-silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: Hi Davut, thank you for your assistance. Sorry about any confusion but my homework assignment is to create a WPF application. Thank you for your help though. I think I'm going to create two controls, one listbox initially populated with the dogs breeds and a combo box with all possible breed listings. The user can then choose additional breeds from the combo box. There will then be an add button to take the choosen breed from the combo box and add it to the dog and listbox. Will see if this works, thanks for your reply!

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't notice any WPF tag. Things are easier in WPF , This guy tell CollectionViewSource for WPF http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html